# how to compare objects inside the same array?

Tags: php, arrays

The first array has some elements with p2p_id as value.

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 70 
  1 => 99
  ...
```

by querying the above p2p_ids, I get the second array that each element is an object with details. I want to compare those elements, find elements that have the same p2p_to value,and the same p2p_type.  I would like to learn how.

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[234]
      public 'p2p_id' => string '70' 
      public 'p2p_from' => string '1124'
      public 'p2p_to' => string '1459' 
      public 'p2p_type' => string 'd_to_x'
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[237]
      public 'p2p_id' => string '99' 
      public 'p2p_from' => string '1327' 
      public 'p2p_to' => string '1459' 
      public 'p2p_type' => string 'd_to_x'
  2=>
  3=>
  4=>
  5=>
  ...
```

Comment: Do both matching elements have to have p2p_id in the first array?

Comment: the second query comes from query the p2p_id(the first array), so, all elements in second array has a p2p_id in the first array. I need to find the ones with the same p2p_to. just updated my question.

Comment: what is the `=> '1'` for? shouldn't just array(70,99) be enough?

Comment: also, i'm assuming you want to compare the two objects with the ids in teh first array. will there always be only 2 ids in the first array to compare? or can there be more.

Comment: the first array comes from query a meta_value that is 1, yes, array(70,99) is fine. There are many p2p_ids. both array have the same number of p2p_ids.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class Post
{
    public $p2p_id, $p2p_from, $p2p_to, $p2p_type;

    /**
     * @param posts  Array   Post objects to compare with this post object
     */
    public function findMatchingPosts($posts){
        $results = array();
        foreach($posts as $post){
            if($post->p2p_to == $this->p2p_to && $post->p2p_type == $this->p2p_type){
                $results[] = $post;         
            }
        }
        return $results;
    }
}
```

Comment: In this method, I think I need to set the member vars to the value that match my condition. Do you mean to run the whole search process inside this class, including searching the p2p_ids(the first array in my question) ?

Comment: Yes I mean to run the whole search process inside the class. `findMatchintPosts(...)` compares the p2p_to and p2p_type attributes but not the p2p_ids.